# Source code editor for HTML/CSS/JS with projects support

Tags: windows, javascript, html, css, portable

I am looking for a source code editor with the support for:

- Javascript, HTML, CSS syntax highlighting
- Auto-completion, Source formatting (for the above languages)
- 'Projects' where you can define project directories, and open all files *you were last using on the project* by opening a 'project'
- *preferably* portable (under 999mb)

Like Notepad++ with *built-in* support for Javascript, HTML, CSS, syntax highlighting, auto completion, source formatting and projects.

I need it to be free, and run on Windows 7.

Comment: [GNU Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd suggest [Adobe Brackets](http://brackets.io)

- **Javascript, HTML, CSS**  --  It was made for those languages.
- **Syntax Highlighting, Auto-completion, Source formatting (for the above languages)**  --  All built in.
- **'Projects' where you can define project directories, and open all files you were last using on the project by opening a 'project'**  --  It opens the last file you were working on in the project; it only opens one file at a time.  The tree is quick to load, though.
- **portable (under 999mb)** -- The portable version isn't official yet, but the source is available.  Also, some people have had success with making it portable themselves. Here is the [PortableApps version](http://portableapps.com/node/39337).

Your miles may vary, but it works pretty well when I use it.

**EDIT:** It very much does reopen the last files you had open under "Working files".  They act as open tabs, but on a vertical plane instead of a horizontal one.

Comment: This is one of the best editors I've ever come across. It has live preview in Chrome as well! Works great on USB and installed version. I'm marking this as the answer - it's great!

Answer (score 10):

You can use [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) which does Syntax Highlighting, Auto-completion, Source formatting, is organized by folder (which is pretty much a project) and can be used for web programming. It is free (the trial has no limit in time or features), works on Windows and a portable version is available.

Sublime's interface is faster than Eclipse, however its autocompletion is limited without plugins.

Unfortunately, it is not free however there is a time-unlimited trial.
[image]

Comment: Note however, that the autocomplete feature is quite flaky, simply suggesting any word on your file. Wither way, it can be fixed with plugins.

Comment: I know a web developer who uses this.

Comment: So, time-unlimited trial = something like winrar? Do I get an annoying notification like in WinRar after 30 days?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the visual effect is; if the requirement is that the software be free, then Sublime doesn't meet it.

Comment: @moopet It's free (in terms of usage), so I'm asking whether it shows a message saying 'please buy'. **For extra information** before I download it. What's the problem in that?

Comment: Nothing as such, but perhaps you could edit the question to say something along the lines of "free or free-to-evaluate" in order that the question will help someone in the future?

Comment: SublimeText2 is nag-ware, but the nag is not too aggressive. But, I was accustomed to TextPad before I switched, and it nags too. It has decent code completion for JS and PHP as far as I can tell. I prefer an add-in "Better Javascript" over the default for JS code highlighting.

Answer (score 7):

It's still in early development, but you might want to look at [Atom](https://atom.io/):

- **Javascript, HTML, CSS** - Supports all of these.
- **Syntax Highlighting, Auto-completion, Source formatting (for the above languages)** Supports all of these functions.
- **'Projects' where you can define project directories, and open all files *you were last using on the project* by opening a 'project'** - Not supported in the base version, but [the project-manager package](https://atom.io/packages/project-manager) adds third-party support for project capabilities, supposedly similar to Sublime Text.
- ***preferably* portable (under 999mb)** - The .zip of the Windows Alpha is currently 62 mb. You just need to extract it and then run Atom.exe, so I think it should be portable. Not sure where the settings are saved though.

Also, it is [open source](https://github.com/atom/atom), under the [MIT License](https://atom.io/faq) and designed to be highly customizable through [packages](https://atom.io/packages). Although still in Alpha, I think it is definitely worth keeping an eye on since it is under very active development.

[image: Atom Editor Screenshot]

Comment: The interface is great, it matches my requirements, but I found Brackets to be even better. +1 for the extra option though!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), which does Syntax Highlighting, Auto-completion, Source formatting, is organized by project and can be used for [web programming](https://netbeans.org/features/html5/). It is free, works on Windows and can be made [portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nbportable/).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Cloud9](http://c9.io). It meets and exceeds your requirements:

- It supports Javascript, HTML, CSS, and many more
- It has Syntax Highlighting, Auto-completion, and Source formatting, using the Ace editor that's used by sites like GitHub - in fact, Cloud9 is the "C" in "Ace"
- Its 'Projects' are not only separate directories with remembered views, but separate *machines*, with views that are synced to the cloud and can be used on multiple devices (by multiple users, if you so need) simultaneously
- As a cloud IDE, it's *very* portable - it can run on any machine with a (modern) web browser, and takes *no* space to install (0 MB).

For the last year and a half, Cloud9 has been the only IDE I do development in. They just pushed a significant overhaul last week, so even if you've checked it out before, take a look!

Comment: The homepage looks great! But I can't get the website to respond! It opens my dashboard, and then Chrome says 'do you want to kill this tab'. Know any solutions?

Comment: The dashboard takes about 20 seconds to load for me (the actual workspaces are quite fast): if you've waited a few minutes and it still hasn't loaded, you can contact support by tweeting @C9Support, emailing support@c9.io, or going to https://c9.io/support/reportabug

Answer (score 4):

There are many tools which can accomplish that.

I personally liked Eclipse IDE for JavaScript developers. I also used Eclipse for Java with HTML/JS plugins to achieve the same thing. It supports tabs, projects, and many other things.
It works on Windows, Linux, Mac OS X.

The only downside of Eclipse is that some users find it too heavy when used on low specs PCs.

Comment: Eclipse is portable. I'm running it from external drive for my own purposes. It's also under 999MB (my own Eclipse configuration with my own plugins is about 170MB).

Comment: I never knew that! I always thought it was a very big program! I'll try it now

Comment: It depends on what you consider "very big". It is huge compared to Notepad++, of course :-) But about 5-10 times smaller than MS Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it does. I'll download it when I'm on my Windows PC, and try it :) +1 for the answer!

Comment: My Eclipse folder is 400 MB, but it depends on the plugins you install.

Comment: Personally I use Eclipse as it has  impressive amount of features, but indeed takes a while to get used to it and is a bit slow. Btw you might want to give a try to Sublime Text, you might find it even cleaner than Netbeans (many people do).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt But Sublime Text is paid isn't it? $70 according to the website

Comment: The trial has no limit in time or features, so in practice, it's free unless you want to be a donation. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in the browser based IDE, you may want to check out https://codenvy.com/

It supports several development environments including HTML/JS.
I played with it some time ago and found it pretty responsive and nice feature-wise.

Also, I used https://koding.com/ long time ago and I was about to recommend it, but it seems like this is not free anymore so it will not match your requirements.
However, while researching for others, I found the following table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_JavaScript_IDE

Comment: Looks good. I was interested in an online one. Cloud9 did not work, but Codenvy's great! +1

Answer (score 2):

I use **SynWrite** editor (free, open source). For your items:

- Syntax Highlighting for HTML/JS/CSS: yes
- Auto-completion for HTML/CSS: yes
- Auto-completion for JS: no such plugin yet (but possible)
- Source formatting: yes for some languages: see [Format plugins](https://sourceforge.net/projects/synwrite-addons/files/PyPlugins/)
- Projects: yes
- portable: yes

[image: Synw]

Comment: Why UI is not so good? U have toolbars, panels, project.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean UI, I meant in comparison to the accepted answer, the colors, and positioning is not as good.

Comment: Not right. In comparision to Brackets, colors are ok, they all can be changed in opt. Brackets has another features. More full support for JS, auto-complete for JS e.g. But SynWrite has more full support for other langs (Brackets is for web, Synwrite is for all, not only web, like Notepad++)

Comment: But extensions are being made ***if*** I ever want other languages support. For now, I need web languages. I'm not saying this is a *bad* program, but I prefer Brackets more.

Comment: I don't see what you want to say. What extentions.. what lang support u need..

Comment: I'm saying, I prefer Brackets. But when you said `But SynWrite has more full support for other langs (Brackets is for web, Synwrite is for all` I said, I don't need them. There isn't anything else I can say - for some reason, I prefer Brackets more.

Comment: Good, use Brackets then, despite it's slooow start.

Comment: SLOW?! It opens in seconds (no exaggeration) on my 4gb ram win7 laptop. Also, Brackets has ***live-preview***. Which is very handy for me, because I often leave out small letters with great importance in my web development languages.

Comment: Hm, so speed is better now. Brackets is good in general: inline editor is gut..

Comment: Yep. Speed is great and the live preview is THE BEST!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to look at [Codelobster](http://www.codelobster.com)

It is my favourite free HTML/CSS/JS editor. It has:

- PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS code highlighting
- PHP, HTML, JavaScript, CSS code collapsing
- HTML autocomplete
- Autocomplete of tags, attributes for current tag, closing tags
- HTML/CSS code inspector
- HTML toolbar
- CSS autocomplete
- Autocomplete of style property names and values
- JavaScript Advanced autocomplete

Comment: be good to confirm whether it is portable and or has project support as defined in the question; other than that nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Komodo Edit](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/) by ActiveState. It meets all of your requirements of,

- Having Javascript, HTML, CSS syntax highlighting
- Having Auto-complete & Calltips support for the above lanuages
- Having Projects support
- Free
- Compatible with Windows 7

Along with those features, it also has,

- Multi-Language Editor
- Track Changes
- Markdown Viewer
- Kopy.io Integration
- Multiple Selections
- Toolbox
- Skins & Icon Sets
- Minimap
- Uses the backbone of Komodo IDE

## [Komodo Edit](http://komodoide.com/komodo-edit/) (open source)

> Komodo Edit is a fast, smart, free and open-source code editor. Switching your trusty code editor is hard, but give Komodo Edit (or its big brother Small Komodo IDE iconKomodo IDE) a try: it'll be worth your while.
>
> Windows, Mac, Linux? Yes.
>   PHP, Python, Ruby, JavaScript, Perl, Tcl, XML, HTML5, CSS 3? Yes, with (customizable) syntax coloring, folding, background syntax checking, and excellent auto-complete and calltips (we call it "code intelligence").
>   What else? Fast open (no more slow poking around for files); remote file editing; Vi keybindings (good ones); and a toolbox with shell command integration, macros and code snippets... all wrapped around a tricked-out editor and an extension mechanism the same as Firefox's.
>
> [image: Komodo Edit UI]

Answer (score 0):

Try AceHTML from Visicom Media.

Just type the name in your search engine. 
Free version is fully functional, and the PRO version 6 has more added functions
This is my workhorse text editor with which I created and am managing my 2 websites.
It is no WYSIWYG, and does work only on Windows (runs fine under my Windows 10 64/32 bit with admin privilege)
It has All criteria you are looking for - too many to list, all on the clean drop down menus, no manual needed.
Switching to the internal viewer is just one click away, instant, no loading your browser to check your code - and with both text editor and viewer full page, this is by far the best Editor program I found so far - none mentioned above even come close.
Have looked for one like that for Linux - but have not found even one I could actually install and use.